# Doesn't show the android email html format when receive outlook

Tags: html, android, email

doesnt show the html format in outlook. please do reply me. sorry for the english

```
private void sendEmail() {
    try {
          String value = "<table>" +
          "<tr>" +
          "<td><b>Name  </b></td>" +
          "<td>android</td>" +
          "</tr><br>" +
          "<tr>" +
          "<td><b>Version</b></td>" +
          "<td>2.2</td>" +
          "</tr>" +
          "</table>";
          Intent email_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          email_intent.setType("text/html");
          email_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "android Details");
          email_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(value));
          email_intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email_intent,"Sending mail.."));
    }catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: omg pls formulate whole sentences and use code tag.

Comment: I think we should force people to stare at the FAQ for 5 hours and attend a "How to ask good questions" seminar before posting is allowed. This hurts me both physically and emotionally - I feel abused as an answer machine here!

Answer (score 0):

You have two `setType()` calls. Eliminate the second. Leave the `email_intent.setType("text/html")` there. See if that helps.

Comment: i remove the second type. i got the same output

Answer (score 0):

The `<table>`tag is apparently not supported by android jet [See this link](http://nowherenearithaca.blogspot.ch/2011/10/some-notes-for-sending-html-email-in.html).

I'm also trying to show a table in an E-mail but I haven't succeeded jet.